# Flexbox self-align not working

Tags: flexbox

I am trying to create a simple nav menu using flexbox. My issue here is that i want to position the li.dropdown-c to the right side of the menu using align-self. I have tried something but its not working. Can anyone tell me what is wrong?

```
<nav>
        <div class="top">
            <ul class="main-ul">
                <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown-c"><a href="#">Four</a>
                    <ul class="in-ul">
                        <li><a href="#">Five</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Six</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Seven</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Eight</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Nine</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Ten</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}

body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color:lightcoral;
    background:#506679;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
}

a {
    color:grey;
    padding:10px 20px;
}

.main-ul {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}

li.dropdown-c {
    display: flex;
    align-self: flex-end;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The align-self property only works for the same direction as align-contents, not justify-content.  Instead, put a margin-left of auto on the li.dropdown and that should work.

```
li.dropdown {
    display: flex;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

Also after testing this in codepen, I realized you're not even selecting the li correctly.  It has class dropdown-c, not dropdown:

```
li.dropdown-c {
    display: flex;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

Comment: Yea it was a mistake when i was copying. Your answer worked thanks!.